# Transparent table captions when using onslide with overprint and setbeamercovered{invisible}

Tags: tables, beamer, overlays, transparency

The following works correctly in that the right table is shown at the right time, and all alignment works as expected.  The only issue is that while the table body is shown as normal, the table captions are shaded as if by `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`.

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Reduced Resource Requirements}
\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \hspace{-2em}
    \begin{itemize}
    \onslide<1>\item $95\%$ decrease disk footprint
    \onslide<2>\item $86\%$ decrease memory footprint
    \onslide<3>\item $62\%$ decrease in runtime
    \end{itemize}
  \end{column}

  \begin{column}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
  \setbeamercovered{invisible}
    \begin{overprint}

      \onslide<1>
        \begin{table}
          \centering
          \caption{On Disk Requirement}
          \begin{tabular}{r|l}
            AST & Source code         \\
                & \& build toolchain  \\
            ASM & Assembly code       \\
                & assembler \& linker \\
            ELF & Compiled executable \\
          \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

      \onslide<2>
        \begin{table}
          \centering
          \caption{Memory(MB) Requirements}
          \begin{tabular}{r|l}
            AST & 1402 \\
            ASM & 756  \\
            ELF & 200  \\
          \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

      \onslide<3>
        \begin{table}
          \centering
          \caption{Runtime (Sec)}
          \begin{tabular}{r|l}
            AST & 229.50 \\
            ASM & 278.30 \\
            ELF & 74.20  \\
          \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

    \end{overprint}
  \end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

I tried wrapping each table in a block, but that lead to TeX stack overflow issues.  Any ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of `\onslide` is different depending on whether it's used inside an `overprint` environment or on its own. Outside, you must use braces to delimitate the argument of your `\onslide` command. That seems to fix it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Reduced Resource Requirements}
\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \hspace{-2em}
    \begin{itemize}
    \onslide<1>{\item $95\%$ decrease disk footprint}
    \onslide<2>{\item $86\%$ decrease memory footprint}
    \onslide<3>{\item $62\%$ decrease in runtime}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{column}

  \begin{column}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
  \setbeamercovered{invisible}
    \begin{overprint}

      \onslide<1>
        \begin{table}
          \centering
          \caption{On Disk Requirement}
          \begin{tabular}{r|l}
            AST & Source code         \\
                & \& build toolchain  \\
            ASM & Assembly code       \\
                & assembler \& linker \\
            ELF & Compiled executable \\
          \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

      \onslide<2>
        \begin{table}
          \centering
          \caption{Memory(MB) Requirements}
          \begin{tabular}{r|l}
            AST & 1402 \\
            ASM & 756  \\
            ELF & 200  \\
          \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

      \onslide<3>
        \begin{table}
          \centering
          \caption{Runtime (Sec)}
          \begin{tabular}{r|l}
            AST & 229.50 \\
            ASM & 278.30 \\
            ELF & 74.20  \\
          \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

    \end{overprint}
  \end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In your case, you don't even need to use `\onslide` if you take advantage of the overlay awareness of `\item`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Reduced Resource Requirements}
\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \hspace{-2em}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<1> $95\%$ decrease disk footprint
    \item<2> $86\%$ decrease memory footprint
    \item<3> $62\%$ decrease in runtime
    \end{itemize}
  \end{column}

  \begin{column}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
  \setbeamercovered{invisible}
    \begin{overprint}

      \onslide<1>
        \begin{table}
          \centering
          \caption{On Disk Requirement}
          \begin{tabular}{r|l}
            AST & Source code         \\
                & \& build toolchain  \\
            ASM & Assembly code       \\
                & assembler \& linker \\
            ELF & Compiled executable \\
          \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

      \onslide<2>
        \begin{table}
          \centering
          \caption{Memory(MB) Requirements}
          \begin{tabular}{r|l}
            AST & 1402 \\
            ASM & 756  \\
            ELF & 200  \\
          \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

      \onslide<3>
        \begin{table}
          \centering
          \caption{Runtime (Sec)}
          \begin{tabular}{r|l}
            AST & 229.50 \\
            ASM & 278.30 \\
            ELF & 74.20  \\
          \end{tabular}
        \end{table}

    \end{overprint}
  \end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This fixes it, thanks for the fix and the clear explanation of the behavior.